# Snakemake: Execute rule based on value of wildcard

Tags: python, workflow, wildcard, snakemake

I have pipeline that takes in input different *species*. If the value of the `{species}` wildcard is "mouse" or "human", I need to do some pre-processing common to both species and execute some rules, otherwise execute another set of rules. This is pseudocode of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SPECIES = ['mouse', 'human', 'pig']

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{species}.done', species=SPECIES),

if wildcards.species in ['mouse', 'human']:
    rule prepare_data:
        output:
            'some.data'

    rule mouse_human:
        input:
            'some.data',
        output:
            '{species}.tmp',
else:
    rule animal:
        # Note file "some.data" is not needed
        output:
            '{species}.tmp',

rule done:
    input:
        '{species}.tmp',
    output:
        '{species}.done',
```

That is: If `{species}` is "mouse" or "human", run rule `prepare_data` (only once) and then run rule `mouse_human` twice, once for human once for mouse. If `{species}` is "pig" or something else run only rule `animal`.

The pseudocode above won't run because `if wildcards.species in ['mouse', 'human']:` is not valid syntax. How can I do that?

A possible solution would be this:

```
rule prepare_data:
    output:
        'some.data',

rule species:
    input:
        'some.data',
    output:
        '{species}.tmp',
    run:
        if wildcards.species in ['mouse', 'human']:
   `        # Do human/mouse stuff using "some.data" and output {species}.txt
        else:
            # Do other stuff and output {species}.tmp, ignore "some.data"
```

However, rule `prepare_data` would always run even if the user's input data does not include "mouse" or "human". This is wasteful and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Is `some.data` independent of wildcards? (same for mouse and human?)

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Yes, `some.data` is independent of wildcards (it's a big reference file downloaded from the internet). It's not needed at all if `{species}` is not human or mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
rule prepare_data:
    output:
        'some.data',
    shell:
        r"""
        some expensive computation
        """

rule prepare_dummy_data:
    output:
        touch('dummy.data'),

rule species:
    input:
        dat= lambda wc: 'some.data' if wc.species in ['human', 'mouse'] \
                         else 'dummy.data',
    output:
        '{species}.tmp',
    run:
        if wildcards.species in ['mouse', 'human']:
   `        # Do human/mouse stuff using "some.data" and output {species}.txt
        else:
            # Do other stuff and output {species}.tmp, ignore {input.dat}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only a minor variation of the answer by @dariober (also OP), but might be preferable in some contexts (e.g. when the condition tree becomes wide):

```py
SPECIES = ['mouse', 'human', 'pig']
SPECIAL_SPECIES_CONSTRAINT = "|".join(['human', 'mouse'])

rule prepare_data:
    output: 'some.data',

ruleorder: species_special > species

rule species:
    output: '{species}.tmp',

rule species_special:
    """Treat mouse/human as special."""
    input: dat='some.data'
    output: '{species}.tmp',
    wildcard_constraints: species=SPECIAL_SPECIES_CONSTRAINT
```

Comment: I'm curious as I see long strings of alternation being used in wildcard constraints.  Is there a loss in performance as the number of alternatives gets very large (>100) vs using a set or dataframe?

Comment: Hmm, interesting, not really sure. In some cases it might be easier to formulate the constraints as exclusion. More generally, I guess the most performant type would be a set, but AFAIK there is noway to implement that right now in snakemake.

Comment: Thanks! I made a minor edit: The `wildcard_constraints` should be named to instruct snakemake about the wildcard(s) to be constrained (`species` here, the only one). Without a name I get a cryptic error `Rule.set_wildcard_constraints() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` (v7.8.5)

Comment: Oops, that's great, thank you for fixing it! :)

Comment: @TroyComi I tested the minimal example with `SPECIES = [str(x) for x in range(0, 5000)];
SPECIAL_SPECIES_CONSTRAINT = "|".join(SPECIES[0:2000])`. I don't see much difference in performance compared to an even simpler example with no constraint and no rule `species_special` (very quick & dirty test though).

Answer (score 1):

Combining SultanOrazbayev's idea of specialized rules with input functions:

```
SPECIES = ['mouse', 'human', 'pig']

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{species}.done', species=SPECIES),

rule prepare_data:
    output:
        'some.data'

def animal_input(wildcards):
    if wildcards.species in ['mouse', 'human']:
        return 'some.data'
    raise ValueError()  # caught by snakemake, will try next rule

ruleorder:
    mouse_human > animal

rule mouse_human:
    input:
        animal_input
    output:
        '{species}.tmp',

rule animal:
    # Note file "some.data" is not needed
    output:
        '{species}.tmp',

rule done:
    input:
        '{species}.tmp',
    output:
        '{species}.done',
```

Instead of raising a value error, you could return an empty string for no input and have a single rule.  Depending on what the rule body does, you may need to handle the case when input is empty separately.